# Finish 2 activities when starting new activity

Tags: android

I have 4 activities: A B C D
When starting the activity D from C, B and C should be removed from the stack. So, the sequence is like:
A > B > C > D then D > A
What I've tried doing when starting D from C is:

```
//create new Intent(C,D)
//setflags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
//startActivity
//finish C
```

When onBackPressed is called in D, activity B is displayed. Seems like it didn't finish. And when checking the stack of activities in Layout Inspector I can see A B D. What do I do to remove B from stack upon calling D or upon onBackPressed of D? Note that I need B when C is started that's why I didn't try calling finish() when starting C.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can (keep in mind the valid uses for this class are usually very rare) manipulate your task stacks at will with Android's [Task Stack Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder)

Answer (score 0):

How about loading A Activity from D Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), A.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This ... is not what the OP asked. This is not using the backstack, this is firing a new intent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is when you press back on the activity D, you simply start your activity A with the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP). This will bring the already existing activity A to the front and clear all other activities.

```
@Override
void onBackPressed() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
     intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note: This will also clear the activity D from the stack so you won't be able to press back and go to the activity D.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```